# Accessing context_data from dispatch method

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm having some trouble while accessing the context_data from the dispatch method from a class based view (DetailView). An exception is being raised with the following message: `'ClientView' object has no attribute 'object'`. Is there anything I'm missing?

```
class ClientView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model=Client
    template_name='core/client.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClientView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # doing something with the context

        return context

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()

        # doing something with the context

        return super(ClientView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

-- EDIT --

The place to route AJAX/regular requests is neither `dispatch` nor `get`, but [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html). This method already receives the context as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

By overriding `dispatch` and calling `get_context_data` directly, you've short-circuited the normal view process. `self.object` isn't actually defined until the `get` method is called.

I doubt you actually need to override `dispatch` at all. Can you explain what your logic is that needs to go there?

Comment: I need to intercept an AJAX request to return a JSON response. The `get_context_data` method has some logic that I'd like to reuse on both cases (AJAX and regular requests).